# How to add a date series to a matrix of data?

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to add dates to a graph of multiple data series using matplot() and I can't find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For example, Let's create a simple matrix of 2 data series:

```
> a <-matrix(1+rnorm(20),10,2)
> a
            [,1]        [,2]
 [1,]  2.7540781  1.31428162
 [2,]  2.4630120  1.04378781
 [3,]  1.7556846 -0.08914417
 [4,]  0.9446534  1.59287973
 [5,]  1.2365692  1.28315556
 [6,] -0.7582962 -0.17436644
 [7,]  1.6519822  3.30782961
 [8,]  0.3979254  0.38058894
 [9,]  1.6826193  1.47889565
[10,]  0.1343743  0.68098755
```

Next, let's create a date series:

```
> dates <- data.frame(days = seq(as.Date('2013-01-01'), by = 'days', length = 10))
> dates
         days
1  2013-01-01
2  2013-01-02
3  2013-01-03
4  2013-01-04
5  2013-01-05
6  2013-01-06
7  2013-01-07
8  2013-01-08
9  2013-01-09
10 2013-01-10
```

Any idea how I can graph series "a" so that it corresponds with the date series "dates"? Specifically, I'd like to be able to plot via matplot(), such as:

```
matplot(a,type="l")
```

With the the series "dates" running along the bottom in standard fashion. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a solution: `matplot(yday(dates[,1]),a,type="l")`?

Comment: No, generates error:                                               Error in as.matrix(x) : could not find function "yday"

Comment: Ah ok. I didn't notice that came from one of my installed packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard of `matplot` before, the most used graphics systems are the basic one (`plot`, `lines`, etc), `lattice` and `ggplot2`. I would use one of these as the amount of user code and examples is very large for those.

I prefer to use `ggplot2`, note that the structure of the data needs to be tweaked a bit to get it to work smoothly with `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
dat = data.frame(dates, a)
dat_melt = melt(dat, id.vars = "days")
ggplot(dat_melt, aes(x = days, y = value, color = variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]